# how to change the text size in bootstrap carousel according to the device screen

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the carousel inner text size accroding to the device screen. Please help me on it.
Below is the code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h2>Hello2 sdfd dljdklf dlkj kld lkjkld lkjkld dlkjlkd ljkl dlkjls slkj </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h2>Hello3</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <h2>Hello4 djkl jd kljld kjd lkjl d lkjkl lkjlk </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here I want to change the h2 text size and the item height should be common for all the four items.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for this.

An example would be like:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .item h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
```

The above media query says that if a screen width has a maximum of 992px, the h2 in the item class should have a font size of 3rem.

If the screen is 993px or greater, this does not apply.

---

### You can use multiple values:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .item h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    .item h2 {
        color: red;
    }
    .item h2 {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
```

The above example, however, is not ideal as it repeats code needlessly. You could obviously condense it into this:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .item h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: red;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
```

---

### You can also use multiple media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .item h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: red;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .item h2 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

The first media query says that if the screen width is less than 992px, the h2 in the item class should have a font-size of 3rem, should be red, and should have an underline.

The second media query says that if the screen goes even further and gets smaller than 768px, the font-size should reduce in size to 2.5rem, the color should be blue, and the underline should be removed.